# Query about sql regarding export the results into excel

Tags: mysql

In this query i tried to export the result into csv... But i am getting error as

> error:----Every derived table must have its own alias

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv"
FROM (SELECT e.server,e.token,e.datetime,e.workstation,f.surname,f.forename,f.token
FROM statistic e, USER f
WHERE e.token=f.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining an alias for your subselect:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv" 
FROM (SELECT e.server,e.token as stat_token,e.datetime,e.workstation,
             f.surname,f.forename,f.token as user_token 
      FROM statistic e, 
      USER f 
      WHERE e.token=f.token) as server_statistics;
```

Comment: @Raj: See my update. This way the columns have different names.

Comment: ok...! thanks a lot juergen d:)      Can u explain y..? u used       (as token) keyword

Comment: @Raj: The `AS` keyword gives the column an individual name. if you have 2 identical column_names in different tables you can name every column like you want to with `AS alias_name`